# Display data in Days range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query output as below

```
Customer  LastModifiedDate

A          1/12/2013
B          1/1/2015
C          1/28/2015
```

Now I need to display the customers count whose details updated in different days range like `(30-60 days)`, `(61-90 Days)` and `90+`(More than 90 days)
For example please see the output below

```
DaysRange      CustomersCount

30-60          1
61-90          1
90+            1
```

Please help me in achieving the above output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, LastModifiedDate, getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN 1 END) AS [30-60],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, LastModifiedDate, getdate()) BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN 1 end) AS [61-90],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, LastModifiedDate, getdate()) > 90 THEN 1 END) AS [90+]
   FROM mytable
```

produces the following output:

```
30-60   61-90   90+
1       1       1
```

With `UNPIVOT` we get the desired result set:

```
SELECT DaysRange, CustomersCount
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, LastModifiedDate, getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN 1 END) AS [30-60],
          COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, LastModifiedDate, getdate()) BETWEEN  61 AND 90 THEN 1 END) AS [61-90],
          COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, LastModifiedDate, getdate()) > 90 THEN 1 END) AS [90+]
   FROM mytable) p
UNPIVOT
   (CustomersCount FOR DaysRange IN ([30-60], [61-90], [90+])
) AS unpvt;
```

**Output:**

```
DaysRange   CustomersCount
30-60       1
61-90       1
90+         1
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this.

```
SELECT DaysRange=CASE
                   WHEN Datediff(DAY, LastModifiedDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN '30-60'
                   WHEN Datediff(DAY, LastModifiedDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN '61-90'
                   WHEN Datediff(DAY, LastModifiedDate, Getdate()) > 90 THEN '90+'
                 END,
       CustomersCount=Count(1)
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN Datediff(DAY, LastModifiedDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN '30-60'
            WHEN Datediff(DAY, LastModifiedDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN '61-90'
            WHEN Datediff(DAY, LastModifiedDate, Getdate()) > 90 THEN '90+'
          END
```